# c# autocad dialog box to detect a new active drawing

Tags: c#, autocad, modeless-dialog

I have a modeless dialog box displaying drawing information. is there a way to detect when another drawing is active and update the dialog box to show the new drawings information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a paletteset instead of a modeless window.

Also, google AutoCAD document events.

Comment: thanks! DocumentActivated event is exactly what I needed. FYI. anyone else in need here is a good example, http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-E619BB54-D531-4640-BB74-B61E6CA13238